# Maven: Conflict jar dependencies

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, conflict

I have a project with two versions of the same jar (they implement similar classes and other specific classes). One jar is used for the java source files in one folder, and the other one is for other folder.

The problem is that it causes a jar conflict (different class implementation), because it seems that both folders use the first jar found in the dependency list, such as:

Jar_file
...
1.0.0

Jar_file
...
2.0.0

Then , my question is how can I to associate these particular dependencies to each folder in the same project?

Cheers.

Comment: Does version 2.0 not include backwards compatibility with version 1.0?

Comment: Why can't you use version 2.0 in all places in your project?

Comment: Hi, there are not backward compatibility :( Really, they are different implementations of the same standard, and not different versions.

Comment: do you have an option to redesign project to use single version? or split it to separate projects, using each own single version? I ask because it looks like you're heading for serious design issue - search web for something like **jar hell**

Comment: Unfortunately, I must not to redesign the project because these source files are part of the core project (for my application). The application is split in different projects, but modifying the structure is not advisable, .... although this is the last option if there are not other solution. Thanks for all your suggestions :)

Comment: As suggested by @gnat above I would seriously suggest splitting your source code into sub-modules on JAR-dependency boundary.  That **is advisable**.  Without it you are trying to tell the javac compiler to compile `src\main\java\**` but to use different classpaths based on the folder (package) it is compiling.  This is not possible without some **serious** Maven hacking _which_ is not worth it.

Answer (score 5):

You should refactor the two "folders" to two distinct maven modules. Each one can now declare the version of the library it requires. Then use the [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to shade the library into the resulting JAR files for both modules. Additionally use the [class relocation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) feature of the maven-shade-plugin to relocate the classes of the library to new packages. Choose different package names for the two versions of the library. You will end up having both versions of the library into two different packages shaded into the resulting JAR files.